# Solving a double integral over transformations of joint bivariate standard normal values

Tags: data-transformation, covariance, bivariate

My problem is about calculating the covariance between transformations of two test statistics based on the correlation between these test statistics. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two test statistics whose joint distribution is a standard bivariate normal distribution with a known correlation. Then, the joint distribution of these two variables can be formulated as follows
$$ f_{X, Y}\left(x, y; \mu = \left[\begin{array}{c} 
0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right], \Sigma = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & \rho\\ \rho & 1\end{array}\right]\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1 - \rho^2)}(x^2+y^2-2\rho xy)\right)$$
The transformation that I want to apply actually transforms $X$ and $Y$ back to a standard normal distribution in two steps. The first step of the transformation is to convert the test statistics into $p$-values, whereas the second step transforms them back to standard normal values. However, there are two types of this transformation. The first type converts the test statistics into one-sided $p$-values which are converted back to standard normal values in the second step. This transformation can be shown as follows
$$X^* = \Phi^{-1}(1 - \Phi(X)) \\
Y^* = \Phi^{-1}(1 - \Phi(Y)),$$
where $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are transformations of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and $\Phi$ is the distribution function of standard normal distribution and $\Phi^{-1}$ is its inverse. This transformation seems trivial for one-sided $p$-values; however, it gets a little more tricky with two-sided $p$-values. For two-sided $p$-values the transformation can be done as
$$X^* = \Phi^{-1}(1 - 2\Phi(1 - |X|)) \\ 
Y^* = \Phi^{-1}(1 - 2\Phi(1 - |Y|)).$$
Although the transformation is different in two-sided $p$-values case, $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are still distributed with a standard bivariate normal distribution, but the covariance between $X^*$ and $Y^*$ is unknown. In a similar problem, [Brown (1975)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2529826?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) showed the calculation of covariance between transformations of two joint standard normal values. The same approach shown in Brown (1975) can be applied to my question by
$$\mbox{Cov}(X^*, Y^*) = \mbox{E}[X^*Y^*] - \mbox{E}[X^*]\mbox{E}[Y^*].$$
Assuming that $X^*$ and $Y^*$ jointly follow bivariate normal distribution $\mbox{E}[X^*]$ and $\mbox{E}[Y^*]$ are equal to $0$. $\mbox{E}[X^*Y^*]$, however, can be calculated by solving the following double integral (for two-sided $p$-values)
$$\int_{-l}^{l}\int_{-l}^{l}X^*Y^*f_{X, Y}\left(x, y; \mu = \left[\begin{array}{c} 
0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right], \Sigma = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & \rho\\ \rho & 1\end{array}\right]\right)dxdy \\
= \int_{-l}^{l}\int_{-l}^{l}\Phi^{-1}(1 - 2\Phi(1 - |x|)) \Phi^{-1}(1 - 2\Phi(1 - |y|)) \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1 - \rho^2)}(x^2+y^2-2\rho xy)\right) dxdy,$$
where $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}[1 + erf(x/\sqrt{2})]$ ($erf(.)$ is the error function) and $l$ is the scalar limit for the test statistics, $X$ and $Y$.

I am trying to solve this double integral with numerical integration method implemented in `R` with `adaptIntegrate` function in package `cubature` where I have a problem. The problem arises from the calculation of the transformed values for a specific value of $X$ (or $Y$). When $X$ (or $Y$) is 0, the two-sided $p$-value becomes 1 (you can try `2 * pnorm(abs(0), lower.tail = FALSE)`). Then, since the $p$-value is 1, when I convert it back to a standard normal value (`qnorm(2 * pnorm(abs(0), lower.tail = FALSE), lower.tail = FALSE)`) results in `-Inf` and it does not allow me to calculate the integral above, because the result converges to infinity.

Do you have any ideas about how I can overcome this problem? Or, do you think the multiplication in the double integral has a closed form so that I can solve it exactly without numerical methods? I'd be glad to hear any help or ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your double integrals are you using "$X$" to mean "$x$" and "$Y$" to mean "$y$"?  If not, then you will need to indicate what they do mean so that we can make sense of the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake, I'll edit the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on "The transformation that I want to apply actually transforms X and Y back to a standard normal distribution in two steps.", I do not think you need to go further on the distribution theory, because following method can resolve your problem.

Given $\left(\begin{matrix} X\\Y \end{matrix}\right) \sim N\left[(\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0 \end{matrix}\right),\Sigma_{2\times 2}\right]$ , then $\Sigma_{2\times 2}^{-\frac 12}\left(\begin{matrix} X\\Y \end{matrix}\right) \sim N\left[(\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0 \end{matrix}\right),\mathrm{I}_{2\times 2}\right]$

So you just need to find $\Sigma_{2\times 2}^{-\frac 12}$.

Comment: This seems like a hint or comment rather than an answer.  Could you more explicitly show how it does answer some interpretation of the question?